# Are there best practices for starting a cluster on machines of different power?

Tags: h2o

I have two machines of differing specs and am starting h2o via command line on each to form a cluster. I then use the flow interface for modeling work.

I’ve noticed that resource use is not evenly spread when running jobs. It tends to under-utilize one machine while maxing out another.

I was wondering if someone could take a look at what I’m doing and offer any tips to adjust / improve. Is this the best way to do it, or are there settings I could change to better maximize the use of resources?

Specs on the two machines:

Machine 1: Intel i7-8700 @ 3.2GHz, 64 GB RAM

Machine 2:  Xeon E5-2680v4 @ 2.4GHZ, 64 GB RAM

Command line to start H2o (running on both of them):

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin\java.exe" -Xmx48g -jar .\h2o.jar -name b_h2o
```

I’m using the latest edition of H2O-3 (3.28.0.4)

Comment: How big is your dataset? And what algorithms are you running (e.g. I found deeplearning distributed well, but randomforest tended to be no quicker than on a single machine).

Comment: Data sets are between 100k and 1M rows, between 50mb and 1.5GB is size (uncompressed text). Algorithms are mainly gbm and autoML. Mostly interested in speeding up autoML.